# How to add UIViews outside of Main WIndow with Storyboard UI?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, storyboard

Before iOS5 i often put a `UIView` in a nib file (beside the main window), gave it a tag and accessed it at runtime.
For example, in a `UITableView` nib, i put a `UIView` beside the `UITableView`, layed it out, and added it as the TableView's headerView at runtime.

When i try to do this with the new Storyboard UI it does not work. As i drag out a UIView from the library to the canvas, it snaps back and nothing happens.

Do you guys maybe got an answer?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, you can't put loose views in a storyboard. But you can still create a regular nib in your project in addition to your storyboard and put your loose views in that.

Comment: How do you make the IBOutlet connection to the UIViews in the xib? I'm dragging from the @property in one of my .h files to the UIView in an xib file and I'm unable to make the connection.

Answer (score 1):

For your particular example, just drag your UIView above your table view, just at the place where you expect to see a header view. Yeah, it's that easy.

For a more general answer, [check my self-answered question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11386111/364446).