# Vertical Paging Using UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView and inside it a UIView and a UITableView. I want to do paging so in the first scroll down, the view swipes down and position TableView to the top (like vertical paging). So when user comes to page, he sees UIView and once swiped down, it scrolls until TableView is positioned at the top of the page, and then classic TableView. Then, if the user swipes up further than the top of TableView, then vertical paging back to UIView.

```
UIScrollView
   |------------------|
   | |--------------| |
   | |    UIView    | |
   | |              | |
   | |              | |
   | |              | |
   | |              | |
   | |              | |
   | |--------------| |
   | |   TableView  | |
   | |              | |
   | |     ...      | |
   | |--------------| |
   |------------------|
```

Before, I used `scrollViewWillEndDragging` for getting swipe up & down gestures. But I am confused how to achieve vertical paging.

```
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {

   if targetContentOffset.memory.y < scrollView.contentOffset.y {

      // Going Up
       if Page != 0 {  // should also check if TableView is at top.
           // Scroll Up To UIView
       }
    } else {
       if 0 < scrollOffset {

            if Page == 0 { 
                // Scroll Down to the top of TableView    

                // I can also check if view is at the top maybe 200 pixels, but      
                // I think this would also work.

            }
       }
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. UIScrollView has pagingEnabled property, just set it to true, but make sure you set content size correctly.

   ```
   let scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: view.bounds)
   scrollView.pagingEnabled = true
   view.addSubview(scrollView)

   let pageSize = view.bounds.size

   let upperView = UIView()
   upperView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

   let lowerView = UITableView()
   lowerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

   let pagesViews = [upperView , lowerView]

   let numberOfPages = pagesViews.count

   for (pageIndex,page) in pagesViews.enumerate(){
       page.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x:0 , y:CGFloat(pageIndex) * pageSize.height), size: pageSize)
       scrollView.addSubview(page)
   }

   scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: pageSize.width, height: pageSize.height * CGFloat(numberOfPages))
   ```
2. Use UIPageViewController with vertical scroll direction, but you need to use a UIViewController for a page.

Comment: Can you please expand on your answer? I got quite confused. I'd be very grateful if you can demonstrate it in a sample project and if it's not too much to ask.

Comment: See the answer , i added a scroll view example.

Comment: Thanks for your example, it makes more sense now. However, I have a question. If I use ScrollView approach, I couldn't find think of a way how to use it with Storyboard.  What I though was, i) Create a ViewController, ii) Add ScrollView with trailing & leading top, bottom, left, right. iii) Enable Paging. At this point, I got confused how to setup/adjust UIView() and UITableView and their constraints on Storyboard. I thought it's not possible to use ScrollView approach with Storyboard, am I right?

Comment: **Edit:** Using the screenshot in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21946121/4705339), I figured out that it's actually possible to create UIView and UITableView, if I drag&drop under ViewController and not inside View (check screenshot in the answer).. @Oleg Huge thanks man!

Comment: **Edit 2:** I wrote it wrong and I cant edit my previous comment. *not under ViewController, under the Scene but as sibling of ViewController

Comment: Is there a way to prevent the views to scroll beyond the UIView? I don't want to UIScrollView to be scrollable above the top View and white dummy screen to be seen. Please take a look [in here, I added screenshots too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36538687/stopping-scrollview-going-above-below-the-bounds)